# FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle inclusion error

Tags: javascript, symfony

When I try to include file of FOSJsRoutingBundle I got an 404 Error.

> GET  https://monSite.com/bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 54 ms]
>
> GET  https://monSite.com/js/routing [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0 ms]
>
> GET https://monSite.com/bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js [HTTP/1.1 404
> Not Found 48 ms]
>
> GET  https://monSite.com/js/routing  [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0 ms]

I follow the [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/installation.html) to install this Bundle.

This is how I include my files :

```
<script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', { callback: 'fos.Router.setData' }) }}"></script>
```

And in my Routing.yml :

```
# app/config/routing.yml
fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"
```

I don't Undestand why this doesn't word.

Edit : I try to acess https://monSite.com/bundles/js and I got an 404 not found. I check in folder web and bundle is create and contains fosjsrouting folder.

Answer (score 0):

I know where I failed, that's because I forget to add bundles in my apache rewrite URL.